# Как сделать адаптивный слайдер?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, javascript, вёрстка, css

Можно ли как-то при помощи CSS сделать подобный слайдер адаптивным/резиновым?

[Пример](http://s1.sendimage.me/8kD2Bhkh_preview.gif)

Сколько гуглил готовые решения для изменения размеров контейнера используют JS...

Comment: а в чем сложность?
контейнеру задайте max-width: 500px (как пример); а для img {max-width:100%;}

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

Comment: http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/ без js

Comment: Ну и? контейнер покажет все слайды. 
http://jsfiddle.net/15tsey48/

Сложность в том, что слайдер должен крутиться по вертикали.

Comment: ну вы даже не добавили js что бы вам могла подсказать,
а так ещё можно использовать @media screen and (max-width: 980px)